# Read directly from a URL and write in a file - Java

Tags: java, file, url

I am reading the contents of a URL and write a file the problem is that I'm not able to write all the content in the file and do not know what I'm doing wrong.

My code,

```
try {
            URL url = new URL(sourceUri);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));


            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            file.createNewFile();

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter bw  = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                bw.write(inputLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }

            br.close();

            System.out.println("DONE");

        }catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ontologies;
    }
```

Please help

Comment: First things first: use java.nio.file. Second: are you absolutely sure that this is a text file? Why don't you just copy the `InputStream`?

Comment: @aioobe not duplicate; this answer uses an obsolete API when in 2015 you have java.nio.file, see my answer.

Comment: @fge, I don't see anything in the linked question that mentions obsolete API. (Some answers are using an obsolete API, sure, but the correct procedure here would be to post an answer to *that* question and close this one as a dup I think.)

Comment: @aioobe hint: `File`

Comment: @fge, I still don't see any `File` in the question. Just because the answers are obsolete doesn't mean a new question should be posted.

Comment: @aioobe hint: `FileOutputStream`

Comment: Are you reading my comments?

Comment: @aioobe I do; and what do you think `file.getParentFile().mkdirs()` do?

Comment: aioobe missing this two lines bw.flush(); bw.close();

Thanks for all the help

Comment: @aedsferrao you should really consider using java.nio.file. Using `File` in 2015 is an anachronism. Look at how simple it is with my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're using a `BufferedWriter` and you don't close it. It has some content in his buffer that is not writing and you're missing.

Try flushing the buffer and closing the `BufferedWriter`:

```
bw.flush();
bw.close();
```

Include this two lines after before your `br.close();`.

Also you can read how `BufferedWriter` works [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html).

And I think you should close `FileWriter`, too, in order to unblock the file.

```
fw.close();
```

**EDIT 1:**

Closing the `BufferedWriter` will flush the buffer for you. You need only to close it.

Comment: you're right, edited.

Answer (score 6):

You are doing many things incorrectly.

First: you don't close all your resources; where is the writer to the file closed?

Second: you use `new InputStreamReader(...)` without specifying the encoding. What says that the encoding on the other end is the one of your JVM/OS combination?

Last but not least, and in fact, this is the most important, you should use java.nio.file. This is 2015 after all.

Simple solution:

```
final Path path = file.toPath(); // or rather use Path directly
Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());

try (
    final InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
) {
    Files.copy(in, path);
}
```

Done, encoding independent, and all resources closed.

Comment: looks like there are issues with Files.copy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java#comment63880638_24041297